# Loose yScroll when move Listbox Class to Toplevel from ROOT - in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

This works fine when the listbox is root, however when I move it to a Toplevel window the scrollbar no longer appears.

Here is the specific code (Note the aassign query has not been applied)

```
class App:

def __init__(self):

    self.listb=Toplevel()
    self.listb.transient(root)
    self.listb.title=('DB View')
    self.vsb = Scrollbar(orient="vertical", command=self.OnVsb)
    self.listNum = Listbox(self.listb, yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
    self.listRoster = Listbox(self.listb, yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
    self.vsb.pack(side="right",fill="y")
    self.listNum.pack(side="left",fill="x", expand=True)
    self.listRoster.pack(side="left",fill="x", expand=True)
    self.listNum.bind("<MouseWheel>", self.OnMouseWheel)
    self.listRoster.bind("<MouseWheel>", self.OnMouseWheel)
    dbi = mdb.connect("localhost", port=3306, user="user", passwd="access", db="interactive_db")
    cursor = dbi.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""SELECT num FROM active_roster""")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.execute("""SELECT firstname, surname, assign FROM active_roster""")
    staff =cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.execute("""SELECT assign FROM active_assign""")
    aassign = cursor.fetchall()
    dbi.close()
    print(rows)
    print(aassign)
    print (staff)

    for results in rows:
        self.listNum.insert("end", results)
    for results2 in staff:
            self.listRoster.insert("end", results2)
    self.listb.mainloop()

def OnVsb(self, *args):
    self.listNum.yview(*args)
    self.listRoster.yview(*args)

def OnMouseWheel(self, event):
    self.listNum.yview("scroll", event.delta,"units")
    self.listRoster.yview("scroll",event.delta,"units")

    return "break"



root = Tk()  
root.title("Main")

root.geometry("900x600")


app=App()
listb = MultipleScrollingListbox()

#PRE-DUAL COLUMN SYNTAX PRE-CLASS DEF

numLabel=Label(root, text="Num #")
numLabel.grid(row=0,column=0)

assLabel=Label(root, text="Assignment")
assLabel.grid(row=0,column=2)


num_input=StringVar()
num_input=Entry(root,textvariable=num_input)
num_input.grid(row=0,column=1)

ass_input=StringVar()
ass_input=Entry(root,textvariable=ass_input)
ass_input.grid(row=0,column=3)


rosterList=Listbox(root, height=6,width=65)
rosterList.grid(row=2, column=0, rowspan=9, columnspan=4)
rosterList.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', on_selection)

 commScroll=Scrollbar(root)
 commScroll.grid(row=2, column=4, rowspan=9)

 rosterList.configure(yscrollcommand=commScroll.set)
 commScroll.configure(command=rosterList.yview)


root.mainloop()
```

I included my original original syntax before I needed to move to a multicolumn layout with the hope of maintaining the same look I started migrating to the Class def - things started to go new awry...

I am new to Tkinter and need some direction here as the OnVsb definition appears to be messing up.

[LISTBOX IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyrHO.png)

Comment: Please try to [create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We're unable to run your code as is, and even if we were, it includes redundant pieces that complicates debugging. We can not reproduce the error.

Comment: If you're certain that your indentation is as exactly the same as what you have here then you need to have all `def`s and what's inside them indented once.

Comment: no prob will update display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the master widget in the Scrollbar call:

```
self.vsb = Scrollbar(self.listb, orient="vertical", command=self.OnVsb)
```

Otherwise it defaults to the first root, which is why it was working before.

Comment: Not surprised you solved it - your script sample I was following - THX. I have it opening in a main window as a transient window.